# Comment dit-on « have at it » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

En anglais, « have at it » veut dire « allez-y », mais avec un certain degré d'encouragement et aussi de permission. Est-ce qu'il y a une phrase française qui exprime la même chose ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

J'ai le sentiment que *have at it* est plus incitateur que « allez-y », effectivement. Le *New Oxford American Dictionary* dit d'ailleurs :

> **have at**: attempt or attack forcefully or aggressively.

Donc, pour *have at it*, je proposerais plutôt (au pluriel) **« foncez ! »**, dans le registre informel.

Comment: Vous avez raison, mais moi, j'utilise la phrase un peu plus familièrement, sans force ou violence. Est-ce que "foncez" est violent?

Comment: Non. Mon fils vient me demander s'il peut faire du vélo dans un endroit nouveau (il a 3 ans), je peux lui répondre « fonce ! » (« vas-y » serait plus neutre). Mais le même serait vrai d'une activité non physique, comme un puzzle.

Comment: On peut d'ailleurs combiner les deux avec bonheur : "vas-y, fonce !".

Comment: Merci beaucoup, je découvre ce forum et vos partages m’ont été très utile.

Answer (score 5):

Il n'y a probablement pas d'expression rigoureusement équivalente. « Allez-y » est plus large. Pour traduire la connotation selon laquelle l'interlocuteur peut agir librement, on peut dire « déchaîne-toi » ou « lâche-toi » (un peu informel, collerait mal avec le vouvoiement).

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble qu'« allez-y » est parfait. Je l'utilise pour autoriser mes enfants à faire quelque chose et aussi pour les encourager.

Comment: L'intonation y fait beaucoup quand-même. "Allez-y" peut aussi être prononcé comme une mise en garde semi-ironique ("a" moins tonique et "y" trainant/montant).

Answer (score 1):

On entend aussi, avec la même signification :

> Fais-toi plaisir ! / Faites-vous plaisir !

...sans aucun lien direct avec un réel *plaisir* physique, bien entendu, ce n'est qu'un encouragement à agir, une autorisation chaleureuse.

Answer (score 0):

En m'appuyant sur la définition identifiée [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/678) et « allez-y », et c'est peut-être un québécisme mais on peut employer l'adverbe [*fort*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fort#Adverbe). Même si « y aller fort » signifie généralement *exagérer*, au Québec à tout le moins il est bien usuel d'employer de manière informelle « vas-y fort ! » pour justement signifier cette permission et cette vigueur dans l'action encouragée. *Allez-y fort !*